# Check if object created without external linkage

Tags: c++, linker, external

Does it exist any way to perform linking-time constraint-check if object instance created as static without external linking, or vise versa?

For example:

```
// test.cpp

// correct
namespace{
static MyObject obj;
}

//test.h

struct Obj
{
    // wrong
    static MyObject m_obj;
}
```

In this case linking error as a diagnostic message is ok.

As far as I understand it is impossible to create something similar in compile-time.

Comment: What is the use-case of what you're trying to find out?

Comment: It is hard to say at all. In general it is architecture and code-style requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Bad way, but you can use macros (I don't think that it is what you need)

```
#define MyObject MyObject
...
#ifdef MyObject
#error somemessagethere
#endif
```

---

Or simply type extern before your declaration in .h file

As I remember, static keyword that is used outside functions means that variable/function instance should exists only in current module.

Comment: Dmitry, I know. The requirement is NOT to create objects of special type outside current module, because sometimes it causes hard-to-detect errors caused by ugly object design. The point is to deny it in linking-time if somebody will forget about this requirement.

Comment: Now I understood original question.
I have no ideas exept writing custom code analyzer tool or forcing code review practice in your team. Because described "// wrong" behavior is absolutely correct from c++ point of view.